# What is the antonym for "economical with truth"?

Tags: word-request, antonyms

He is not "***economical*** with the truth". I need a single word that means its opposite

> He is ____ with the truth.

What word do I put in the blank? Non-Economical?

Answer (score 4):

"He is economical with the truth" means that this person does not often tell the truth.

The opposite would be "he is [liberal](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/liberal) with the truth."

> Liberal means **giving**, using, or taking a lot of something, or existing in large quantities.